# Can this product measure be extended to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}$? if so, how?

Tags: measure-theory

**Consider two measure spaces:**

**1)** $\left([q_0, \infty), \mathcal B([q_0, \infty)), \lambda_{q_0} \right)$, where  $\lambda_{q_0}$ be a  Lebesgue measure generated by a parameterized Lebesgue length of the form $l\left([a,b]\right)=q_0^{-\zeta} |b-a|,$ and $q_0>0$.

**2)** $\left([q_0, \infty), \mathcal B([q_0, \infty)), \mu_{q_0} \right)$, where  $\mu_{q_0}$ is a probability measure associated implied by the standard Pareto distribution; that is,   $\mu_{q_0}\left(A\right)= q_0^\zeta  \int_A\zeta q^{-\zeta-1}  \lambda _1(dq)$, where $A$ is a measurable set from $[q_0, \infty)$ and $\zeta \geq 1$. (To have it defined for sets the integral here is replaced by the standard Lebesgue integral. To define it I reused $\lambda_{q_0}$ as described in point 1 above.)

By the product measure theorem, we define product measure $\nu=\lambda_{q_0} \mu_{q_0}= \int_A \zeta q^{-\zeta-1}  \lambda _1(dq)$ and note that it can be uniquely extended to some  $\sigma$-finite measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the Cartesian product $[q_0, \infty) \times [q_0, \infty)$.

**My question is about the possibility of extending the domain of the measure $\nu$ about to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over  $\mathbb{R}^2_{++}:=(0,\infty)$  instead of  $[q_0, \infty)\times [q_0, \infty)$ (to drop $q_0$ altogether).**

Can it be done? How?

Latest attempt:

I tried to define an outer measure to invoke the Caratheodory extension theorem, akin to the standard proof of the extension of the Lebesgue length/volume. Not very confident in the reasoning because of obvious technical difficulties with the ill-defined integral at zero but could not construct a counterexample. Here is the sketch of my reasoning so far:

**Step 1:** Let the covering be a countable collection of rectangles  $\{C_i: i\in \mathbb{N}\}$, where  $C_i=I_i \times I^\prime_i$ for some    closed intervals $I_i$, $I^\prime_i$ on $\mathbb{R}_{++}$. Define the "volume" function as  $v(\pi):=\sum_i^\infty \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[ |I_i| \int_\mathcal{I_{i'}} \zeta \left(q+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-\zeta-1}  \lambda _1(dq)\right]$ (by the monotone convergence theorem this monotone sequence of well-defined integrals is meant to return an infinite measure whenever the original integral would be ill-defined).

**Step 2:** Consider the candidate outer measure given by  $\mu^\ast:=\inf_{\pi \in \mathcal{P}(A)} v(\pi)$, with $\mathcal{P}(A)$ describing all possible coverings of the set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2_++$ by rectangles.

**Step 3:** Verify countable subadditivity (if $A \subset \cup_i^\infty A_i$ then $\mu^\ast \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu^\ast(A_i))$ by defining a restricted covering as follows: $\pi\in \mathcal P_0 \Leftrightarrow \exists \pi_i \in \mathcal P(A_i), \pi_i=\{C_{1}^i,C_{2}^i,...\}$, $i\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\pi=\{C^1_1,C^1_2,...,C^2_1,C^2_2,...,C^3_1, C^3_2,...\},$ and then use the following evaluation: $\mu^{\ast}(A) \leq \inf_{\pi \in \mathcal{P}(A)} v(\pi)= \inf_{\pi \in \mathcal{P}(A)} \left( \sum_j \sum_i    v(C_i^j)   \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^\ast (A_i).$ (Notes: First inequality  by restriction of inf to subset; second equality by definition; last inequality by the fact that inf is applied jointly to all sets as opposed to each set individually. There is a possibility of infinity here  that I am not sure how to deal with. The step involving monotone convergence makes me very uneasy in the context of second equality and also in general.)

Am I on the right track? Is there some other approach I should try instead? Is there a counterexample showing such an extension is not possible? These are my questions.

Your help will be very much appreciated! Thanks.